# Retrieving repeated items in a list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list

Given a sorted list, I would like to retrieve the first repeated item in the list using list comprehension.
So I ran the line below:

```
list=['1', '2', '3', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c']
print(k for k in list if k==k+1)
```

I expected the output "a". But instead I got:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0021AB30>
```

I'm pretty new at this, would someone be willing to clarify why this doesn't work?

Comment: I'm not sure that list comprehension is the appropriate way to do this, because list comprehension is designed to take members of an existing enumerable. But you're after a single element

Comment: I took a closer look and first of all I just did a generator expression not a list comprehension, that's why I got the error... a list comprehension would be [k for k in list if k==k+1] but if I do this I get:"TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple." That's because I was trying to use k as an index ,so when I do k+1 it tries to concatenate str with int, hence the second error. Now I tried playing around with enumerate but I got stuck. I'm beginning to think this is not such a great idea...

Comment: Yeah I noticed both of those, I just wanted to await your answer incase you noticed, which you did

Comment: This isn't what list-comprehensions are for.

Comment: @blhsing I never thought of comparing elements with and offset that way.Thank you!

Comment: @Eugene Rysaj list comprehensions are definetly more clear to me now, and yes I should keep the code simple and readable. At this stage I am always aware that any code I write can be constructed in a more efficient way, so sometimes I get ahead of myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to confuse the notion of list element and index.

For example the generator expression iterating over all items of list `xs` equal to its predecessor would look like this:

```py
g = (xs[k] for k in range(1, len(xs)) if xs[k] == xs[k - 1])
```

Since you are interested only in first such item, you could write

```py
next(xs[k] for k in range(1, len(xs)) if xs[k] == xs[k - 1])
```

however you'll get an exception if there is in fact no such items.

As a general advice, prefer simple readable functions over clever long one-liners,
especially when you are new to language. Your task could be accomplished as follows:

```py
def first_duplicate(xs):
    for k in range(1, len(xs)):
        if xs[k] == xs[k - 1]:
            return xs[k]

chars = ['1', '2', '3', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c']
print(first_duplicate(chars)) # 'a'
```

P.S. Beware using `list` as your variable name -- you're shadowing built-in type

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the first repeated item in the list you can use the `next` function with a generator expression that iterates through the list zipped with itself but with an offset of 1 to compare adjacent items:

```
next(a for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:]) if a == b)
```

so that given `lst = ['1', '2', '3', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c']`, the above returns: `'a'`.